# How to read data from a REST URL and load to a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a rest service URL like:

```
http://domain.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services/appData?f=json&pretty=true
```

which looks like:

```
{"currentVersion" : 10.05, 
  "folders" : [], 
  "services" : [
    {"name" : "appData/Drainage", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Parks", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Planning", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/QNet", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Sanitary", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Street_Lights", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Survey", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Transportation", "type" : "MapServer"}, 
    {"name" : "appData/Water", "type" : "MapServer"}
  ]
}
```

How can load all names after `appData/` to a list called `servicesList` in Python? I tried something like

```
myUrl = "http://domain.ca/ArcGIS/rest/services"
myRequest = myUrl
response = urllib2.urlopen(myRequest)
myJSON = response.read()
```

Is the the correct way?

Comment: What happened when you tried it the way you said you did?

Comment: use json module to parse this json using `json.loads(myJSON)`. it will convert it into a python dictionary, from which you can get the services key which will return a list of dictionaries. get the name attribute from each dictionary in list and replace the string "appData/" with "" and append the result to service list

Comment: Getting  a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Category not found`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the op probably meant it as a sample domain.

Comment: @technusm1 I wanted to show OP how to do this with requests, but I can't reproduce an example.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the first 100 Chars you get from `print(myJSON)`-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 serviceList= []
    for x in myJSON["services"]:
       name = x["name"]
       serviceList.append(name[name.index("/")+1:]) #Find the index of the / and add everything after it to the list
```

This would loop over all the names in the services and add the part after the `/` to the service list as you want.

EDIT:
You will also have to convert the string you read to JSON first. To do that:

```
import json
newJSON = json.loads(myJSON)
```

You can find documentation about json [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html)

Comment: Thanks anon but I am getting this error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` on  `newJSON = json.loads(myJSON)`